# Regex: find every occurrence between EQUAL delimiters, but no text between occurences

Tags: regex, vb.net

An example makes my Question quite simple to understand:

```
"SELECT @COLUMN@ FROM @TABLE@"
```

I want to get `["COLUMN","TABLE"]`, but not `["COLUMN"," FROM ","TABLE"]`.

It's not SQL-specific. (searching for Regex pattern string)

I want to get everything between two delimiters (@), not only chars like in the example.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assumed, you want to capture **a word** between `@` chars,
without any spaces, so `@ FROM @` is not any candidate string,
because it contains spaces.

To capture such a string use `@([A-Z]+)@`.

Of course, you have to use **global** and probably
also **case insensitive** options.